# Azure defender for cloud malware scanning event grid topic with private endpoint doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I would like to trigger an Azure function when Defender for Storage has completed a malware scan for a file. I have successfully achieved this using a custom Event Grid topic. However, the issue arises when attempting to utilize a private endpoint connection.

[image]

Upon trying to add a private endpoint, I encountered the following error message:

> Publishing to XXXX-MALWARE-SCANNED.WESTEUROPE-1.EVENTGRID.AZURE.NET by client 192.168.1.100 is rejected due to IpAddress filtering rules. For troubleshooting, visit https://aka.ms/egpublisherrorcode403.

The provided link suggests adding the IP address (192.168.1.100) to the address range field. However, upon adding it (with public networks selected), another error occurred:

> The principal associated with access token presented with the incoming request does not have permission to send data to /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/xxxx-malware-scanned.

I am not well-versed in private endpoints. How should it be configured for this purpose? Alternatively, if I can configure IP restriction, how can it be done? The error message for it ("The principal associated with...") is unclear to me.

**How can I either enable a private endpoint or IP restriction for this purpose?**

Answer (score 0):

> The principal associated with access token presented with the incoming request does not have permission to send data to /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/myResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/xxxx-malware-scanned.

In order to resolve this error, ***Make sure you add Function App managed identity `Event Grid Data sender` role or Custom role at the Event Grid topic level like below***:-

***Enable Function App managed identity:-***

[image]

Assigned the Function app managed identity, ***EventGrid Data Sender role***:-

[image]

[image]

If **`EventGrid Data Sender`** role does not work, Make sure you create a ***`Custom Role` to send data to the EventGrid Topic*** at a ***Data plane*** operation level by referring to this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60823873/creating-an-azure-event-grid-topic-error-does-not-have-authorization-to-perfo) by Gaurav mantri.

***If you are using an Azure AD service principal or User principal to send data to EventGrid Topic make sure you add the `EventGrid Data Sender` role to that service principal.***

Also, enable the **`SAS authentication for your storage account`** while creating the **Topics**:-

[image]

**References:-**

[Event delivery, managed service identity, and private link - Azure Event Grid | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/managed-service-identity#create-event-subscriptions-that-use-an-identity)

[Authenticate Event Grid publishing clients using Microsoft Entra ID - Azure Event Grid | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/authenticate-with-microsoft-entra-id?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_EventGrid#client-configuration-steps-to-use-microsoft-entra-authentication)